# Function with input not working

Tags: javascript, css

I have written a function for placeholder functionality of an input field. It works if I write the on/off functions separately, but it's not working when keeping an input variable and `if` construct. Please help regarding what's wrong in syntax or logic.

```
function placeholder(x) {
    if (x=="1") {
        if (document.getElementById("search_field").value=="") {
            document.getElementById("placeholder").style.display="inline";
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("placeholder").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("search_field").focus();
    }
}
```

---

```
<input id="search_field" type="text" value="" onfocus="placeholder(0);" onblur="placeholder(1);">
<span id="field_def" onclick="placeholder(0);" >
    <img src="mag.jpg">
    <p id="placeholder">Search</p>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `placeholder` attribute. It is accepted by all major modern browsers and will save you from adding extra HTML tags and JavaScript code.

```
<input type="text" name="someName" placeholder="Some Text">
```

Following is the alternative for old browsers where `placeholder` is not recognized:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4NCYx/)**

**HTML:**

```
<input id="search_field" type="text" value="Enter keywords..." onfocus="ph(1);" onblur="ph(0);" onclick="ph(1);">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function ph(x) {
    var txtSearch = document.getElementById("search_field");
    if (x == 1) {
        if (txtSearch.value == "Enter keywords...") {
            txtSearch.value = '';
        }
    }
    else {
        if (txtSearch.value == "") {
            txtSearch.value = 'Enter keywords...';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its not compatible with older browsers since its html5.
i see a lot of websites using both placeholder attribute and javascript they overlap over each other on html5 supported browsers again one has to check for compatibility and use appropriate one. dont you feel that it is too laborious?

Comment: @Sagi_Avinash_Varma See the edit for old browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Try without the quotes on 1 when evaluating x:

```
 function placeholder(x){
if(x==1){
    if(document.getElementById("search_field").value==""){
    document.getElementById("placeholder").style.display="inline";
    }   
}
else{ 
    document.getElementById("placeholder").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("search_field").focus();
    }
}
```

**Also, remove the ";" when calling the function:**

```
<span id="field_def" onclick="placeholder(0)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the function was called or not.

If not then change it:

```
<input id="search_field" type="text" value="" onfocus="javascript:placeholder(0)" onblur="javascript:placeholder(1)">
```